# Errors occuring when make-ing Aircrack-ng on raspberry pi

Tags: compilation, raspbian, aircrack-ng

As it can be seen in the log I have some errors when trying to compile Aircrack on my Raspberry pi B+ running latest raspbian. I can't manage to find out what's wrong.
(I have also installed libnl)

```
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0
-DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3
-Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o
osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3
-lnl-3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:189: recipe for target 'wpaclean' failed
make[1]: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev
sudo ln -s /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnl-genl-3.so.200  /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnl-genl-3.so
```

You have installed libnl-3-dev but it doesn't create proper library link.

Answer (score -3):

Try "sudo make" and "sudo make install"
You also might need to install the libssl-dev package if you havent done so already.